# Jquery plugin confirmOn not work with ajax loaded DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me.
I don`t know how to work plugin with DOM element loaded after $(document).ready
This is sample

```
 $('.menu_confirm').confirmOn('click', function (e, confirmed) {
        if (confirmed) { // Clicked yes
alert (1);
}else { // Clicked no
 alert (2); 
        }
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(body).confirmOn('click', '.menu_confirm',function (e, confirmed) {
    if (confirmed) { // Clicked yes
      alert (1);
    }else { // Clicked no
      alert (2); 
    }
 });
```

Better you use a subcontainer for reference (better performance):

```
 $('.heres_ajaxcontent').confirmOn('click', '.menu_confirm',function (e, confirmed) {
    if (confirmed) { // Clicked yes
      alert (1);
    }else { // Clicked no
      alert (2); 
    }
 });
```